# How to merge two dictionaries in DolphinDB?

Tags: dictionary, dolphindb

I would like to merge two dictionaries, “a” and “b”, in DolphinDB. In Python, I can use the `**` operator to unpack the two dictionaries, and then use `{**a, **b}` to create a new dictionary containing all the key-value pairs extracted from the unpacked dictionaries. Is there a similar or efficient method in DolphinDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1: use assignment

```
a[b.keys()] = b.values()
```

Method 2: use the `dictUpdate` function

Below is an example:

```
y=dict(1 2,1.0 2.0);
x=dict(INT,ANY)
x[3]=3
x[5]="5"
x.dictUpdate!(append!, y.keys(), y.values(),x->array(x.type(), 0, 512).append!(x))
```

Note:

This method is only suitable when new keys do not exist in the dictionary to be updated.

The parameter *initFunc* can be specified only when the values of the dictionary “x“ are tuples.